# Can't see menu images in Unity tweak tool

Tags: unity-tweak-tool

I have installed Unity Tweak Tool on Ubuntu 15.10 and it's working fine. But the images with menu options are missing.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I solve this issue? I also reinstalled this tool but same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: I ran code above, but issue is still unresolved. It reset settings but images are still missing.